# Is there a Way to Create Customer Segment based on Order Values for a specific period

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, customer, customer-segmentation

Is there a Way to Create Customer Segment based on Order Values for a specific period in Magento enterprise? I would like to create customer segment for customers who did any transaction of an order value of $1000 or more for a month.. Is that possible? If i do it based on Sales Value , it take the complete total sales value on a particular transaction?

Comment: Which version of EE are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it should be possible:

[image: Screenshot of customer segment conditions]